# how do i use group by in only one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Correct me if the question title is wrong ,

i have table in MySQL Named `sales`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_QUANTITY | PRODUCT_TYPE | In_Box_Count_Sell | ExpiryDate |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     kkkkk    |       4          |   Count      |         1         |   2021-02-28 |
|     kkkkk    |       4          |   Count      |         1         |   2021-02-21 |
|     yuyuyu   |       3          |   Count      |         5         |   2021-02-21 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another Table Named `depot`

```
    --------------------------------
    | ITEM_NAME | PRODUCT_QUANTITY | 
    --------------------------------
    |   kkkkk   |      12          |
    |   yuyuyu  |      15          |
    --------------------------------
```

I have used this query :

```
SELECT `ExpiryDate`,`PRODUCT_NAME` As pdname,sales.`PRODUCT_QUANTITY`,`In_Box_Count_Sell`,`PRODUCT_TYPE`,(`depot`.`PRODUCT_QUANTITY`) As InDepotQuent FROM ((`sales`
INNER JOIN depot ON sales.PRODUCT_NAME = depot.ITEM_NAME)
INNER JOIN bill_info ON sales.BILL_NUMBER = bill_info.BILL_NUMBER)
WHERE bill_info.BILL_TYPE = 'مشتريات' 
ORDER BY `sales`.`PRODUCT_NAME`  ASC
```

And its result is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  ExpiryDate | pdname | PRODUCT_QUANTITY | In_Box_Count_Sell | PRODUCT_TYPE | InDepotQuent |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2021-02-21 | kkkkk  |       10         |        1          |     Count    |      12      |
|  2021-02-28 | kkkkk  |       4          |        1          |     Count    |      12      |
|  2021-08-25 | yuyuy  |       3          |        5          |     Count    |      15      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what i need to get is the `atc` = the sum of `PRODUCT_QUANTITY` - the sum of `InDepotQuent`  and the result will  be like this :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  ExpiryDate | pdname | PRODUCT_QUANTITY | In_Box_Count_Sell | PRODUCT_TYPE | InDepotQuent | atc |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2021-02-21 | kkkkk  |       10         |        1          |     Count    |      12      |  2  |
|  2021-02-28 | kkkkk  |       4          |        1          |     Count    |      12      |  2  |
|  2021-08-25 | yuyuy  |       3          |        5          |     Count    |      15      |  12 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the `sum of PRODUCT_QUANTITY  = (14) - sum of InDepotQuent = (12)`

The `atc = 2`

And taking into account the name of the pdname are similar in a table !

Comment: In your sql statement the formula behind atc is InDepotQuent - PRODUCT_QUANTITY, while your description says the opposite. Which one is the correct formula? Pls also provide sample data for both tables.

Comment: @Shadow Done ... have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions, if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT ExpierDate, PRODUCT_NAME As pdname, s.PRODUCT_QUANTITY, 
       In_Box_Count_Sell, PRODUCT_TIPE, d.PRODUCT_QUANTITY As InDepotQuent,
       SUM(s.PRODUCT_QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_NAME) - d.PRODUCT_QUANTITY as atc
FROM sales s JOIN
     depot d
     ON s.PRODUCT_NAME = d.ITEM_NAME JOIN
     bill_info bi
     ON s.BILL_NUMBER = bi.BILL_NUMBER
WHERE bi.BILL_TIPE = 'مشتريات' 
ORDER BY s.PRODUCT_NAME ASC;
```

Comment: ( #1054 - Unknown column 'InDepotQuent' in 'field list' ) Can you make sure that the query you have written is working properly ?

Comment: @AdeebMark . . . I didn't realize that is a column alias.  I fixed the query.